# undefined method `students' for #<Period:0x007fb7fff47360>

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to add students I created in a school, to a teachers period (class).  I'm not looking to create a new student in a period, but rather select students from a list I created in the school.  I was able to list the students in a period, but cannot add them to the period.  I'm unsure if I use the build method or something different.  I'm currently getting an undefined method error and am just unsure which way to go from here.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Class Name:</strong>
   <%= @period.period %>

    </p>

<%= link_to 'Delete Period', [@period.teacher, @period],
           method: :delete,
           data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>



 <h2>Add a student to period</h2>
 <%= form_for([@period, @period.students.build]) do |f| %>

  <p>
    <%= check_box_tag "school[student_ids][]", student.id %>
    <%= link_to student.name, edit_school_student_path(@school, student) %>
  </p>

<p>
<%= f.submit %>
</p>
<% end %>


class Period < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :teacher
  has_many :students
end

class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :teachers, through: :periods
end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :school
  has_many :periods
  has_many :students, through: :periods 
end

class School < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teachers, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :students, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :schoolads, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: Could you paste your `period`, `student` and `teacher` models?

Comment: Please show your models and there relationship..

Comment: just added the models!